# One char from the other bool function

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to have a function that is going to return true if and only if a char* s could be obtained from char* t by simply crossing out certain letters e.g. `g("ERT", "EAARYT")=true` and `g("ERT","ABCT")=false`.

My idea for this code is the following:

```
bool g(char* s, char* t) {
    for (int i=0; s[i]!=0;i++) {
        for (int j=i; t[j]!=0; j++) {
            if (s[i]==t[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Obviously it does not work as it only check whether the first letter is present and then immediately returns true.
How should i change that?

I would prefer to use nested loops/if constructions this should be more than doable with that.

Comment: Does not work properly then.

Comment: Have you considered not returning true immediately?

Comment: Also, use one loop. Assigning `i` to `j` is wrong.

Comment: Before the end of the first loop? Or where?

Comment: @LogicStuff but how to iterate through char then?

Comment: @Mrowkacala Build something on top of simple iteration through an array pointed-to by `t`.

Comment: Try to develop your algorithm on paper first. Do it one simple step at a time, write down all the steps, and the values of of possible variables. Refine. And when you have something which seems to work on paper, then go and write some code to implement the algorithm. Again, do one step at a time, and if something doesn't seem to work then use a debugger to step through the code to make sure the code does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Is g("ERRT", "ERT")=true ?

Comment: Should be true yes.

Comment: _"it does not work as it only check whether the first letter is present and then immediately returns true"_ Then don't do that thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**return true if and only if char *s could be obtained from char *t by simply crossing out certain letters**. This means two things :

- [A] `t` should contain all the characters of `s`. Therefore, we need to store the count of characters.
- [B] `t` should contain all the characters of `s` as well as `t` should have common characters in order same as `s`.

**Solution A:** Order of characters in `t` does not matter. What it matters is all the characters in `s` should be present in `t`.

`g("ERRT", "ERT") = false`

`g("ERRR", "ERRT") = false`

`g("ERRR", "RRRE") = true`

```
bool g(char* s, char* t) 
{
    int hash[256] = {0};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; t[i]; ++i) 
    {
        hash[t[i]] += 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; s[i]; ++i) 
    {
        if(hash[s[i]] <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            hash[s[i]] -= 1;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Solution B:** Order of characters in `t` **does** matter. Also all the characters in `s` should be present in `t`.

`g("ERRT", "RERT") = false`

`g("ERRR", "RRER") = false`

`g("ERRR", "RRRE") = false`

g("**ERTR**", "R**ER**GR**T**B**R**") = true

```
bool g(char* s, char* t) 
{
    if(strcmp(LCS(s, t), s) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

where, `LCS(s, t) =` [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can return with `false` if a latter is not found, succeed otherwise:

```cpp
bool g(const char* s, const char* t) {
  for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = i; t[j] != 0; j++) {
      if (s[i] == t[j]) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Also, consider using `strspn` for counting matching characters

```
bool g(const char* s, const char* t){
    return strspn(s, t) == strlen(s);
}
```

Comment: interesting, but will `strcpn` work with non-consecutive match like in this question ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like-

```
bool g(char* s, char* t){
    int sLen=strlen(s);
    int tLen=strlen(t);
    if(sLen > tLen)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<tLen;i++)
    {
        if(s[j] == t[i])
        {
            j++;
        }
        if(j == sLen)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This assumes `s` and `t` are sorted by characters inside them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int c = 0;
    int len = strlen(s); // Find the length of string
    for(i=0; s[i]!=0;i++)
    {
            for(j=0; t[j]!=0; j++)
            {
                    if(s[i]==t[j])
                    {
                            c++; // count the character, If count is equal to length then true.
                    }
            }
    }
    if (len == c) 
            return true;
    else
            return false;
```

Comment: if(len>=c) return true;

Comment: @user1438832 count number is equal to length, not more or less.

Comment: @user1438832 Ok, no problem.

Comment: But what if s is "XXXX" and t is "X" your code return true.

Comment: Yes, because first string every character compare with second string.

Comment: @user1438832: it's right. The op must return false early if the length of the first string is larger than the second.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the function using only one loop and substituting the second loop for the standard C function `strchr`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

bool g( const char *s, const char *t )
{
    size_t m = std::strlen( s );
    size_t n = std::strlen( t );

    const char *p;

    while ( ( m != 0 ) and not ( n < m ) and ( p = std::strchr( t, s[0] ) ) )
    {
        ++p;
        n -= p - t;
        t = p;
        --m;
        ++s; 
    }

    return m == 0;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "g( \"ERT\", \"EAARYT\" ) = " 
              << std::boolalpha << g( "ERT", "EAARYT" ) << std::endl;       

    std::cout << "g( \"ERT\", \"ABCT\" ) = " 
              << std::boolalpha << g( "ERT", "ABCT" ) << std::endl;     
}
```

The program output is

```
g( "ERT", "EAARYT" ) = true
g( "ERT", "ABCT" ) = false
```